# Standard name for the "walking span" category

Tags: category-theory, definition

Is there a standard name for the category made of 3 objects describing a span, aka, with one central point and two arrows glued at their origin, going each in their own direction toward the two other distinct points.

This would symmetrize the category $2$, which has two objects and a single arrow between them. Said otherwise, "walking span" is a pushout in $Cat$ of $\delta_0 : 1 \to 2$ with itself.

Comment: Some people denote this category by $\Lambda^2_0$ and call it the $(2,0)$-horn.

Comment: Whenever I've needed this in my work, I just gave the diagram and gave it a name.

Comment: Personally, I think walking span is a perfectly acceptable name.

Comment: Why is the span *walking*?

Comment: @Jochen true... it's more like pointing, referencing, or coordinate-ing, or matrix-ing. the "walking" terminology presumably refer to the collection of *all* the "walks" you could take in a category, which arise from functors from 2 to that category.

Comment: @asdq thank you for reminding me of those